# Move rows based on criteria within string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table in Excel with this format:

the first column is `Name` and
 the second one `Phone` with phone number format `XX YYYYYZZZZ`
 (e.g. `12 981152989`). `XX` is the state code, `YYYYY` the first part of number, and `ZZZZ` the second part of number.

I have to do a function to analyze if the **third** character (XX**Y**Y....) of phone number **is equals 7 or 8 or 9**. If true, move the entire row to another sheet.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula cannot move a row to another sheet. However it can identify which rows to move, perhaps prior to filtering. Please try:

```
=IF(1*MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""),3,1)>6,"#","")
```